# How to draw an arrow from one block to two blocks with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I want to draw a diagram like below, but I don't know how to draw an arrow that from one block to two blocks, like the one to source1/source2 and how to draw an arrow from two blocks to one block, like the one from source1/source2. Could someone help me please!
[image]

This is what I can do to my best:

```
\tikzstyle{rect} = [draw, rectangle, minimum height = 4em, text width = 6em, text centered]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3cm, auto]
        \node[rect](signal) {Signal};
        \node[rect, right of=signal](STFT) {STFT};
        \node[rect, right of=STFT](sep) {DNN/RNN};
        \node[rect, right of=sep](speech) {$Source_1$};
        \node[rect, below of=speech](music) {$Source_2$};
        \node[rect, below of=sep](mask) {Time Frequencey Masking};
        \node[rect, left of=mask](ISTFT) {ISTFT};
        \node[rect, left of=ISTFT](eval) {Evaluation};

        \path[line] (signal) -- (STFT);
        \path[line] (STFT) -- (sep);
        \path[line] (sep) -- (speech);
        \path[line] (sep) -- (music);
        \path[line] (mask) -- (ISTFT);
        \path[line] (ISTFT) -- (eval);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please show us a partial solution you have tried.

Comment: Welcome! If you provide the code for the diagram without the problematic arrows, somebody will be happy to show you how to do the arrows. It isn't really fair to expect people to draw the whole thing from scratch. There are a *lot* of questions about drawing this kind of diagram, though, so it is puzzling that you've not found anything to help already.

Comment: Personally, I don't think the diagram is very clear as it is drawn at all. Why is there an arrow from nowhere to Time Frequency Masking? That doesn't make sense to me. But maybe this is standard notation and nothingness has special symbolic value here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, chains, fit, positioning, scopes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
            > = angle 90,
node distance = 6mm and 8mm,
   box/.style = {draw, minimum height=10mm, minimum width=27mm,
                 align=center, join=by ->, on chain}, 
         font = \sffamily
                    ] 
{ [start chain = A going right]
\node[on chain] {Signal};
\node[box]      {STFT/log-mel};
\node[box]      {DNN/RNN};
}
{ [start chain = B going left]
\node[box,below=of A-3]      
                {Time Frequency\\ Masking};
\node[box]      {ISTFT};
\node[box]      {Evaluation};             
} 
\node (s1)  [right=of A-3.north east] {Source\textsubscript{1}};
\node (s2)  [right=of A-3.south east] {Source\textsubscript{2}};
% 
\node[draw, dotted, inner sep = 5mm, xshift=1mm, fit=(A-3) (B-1) (s1)] {};
\draw (A-3.east) -- ++ (4mm,0) coordinate (s0);
\draw[->] (s0)  |- (s1);
\draw[->] (s0)  |- (s2);
\draw[->] (A-3 -| s1.east) -- + (4mm,0) |- (B-1);  
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Nodes position is determined by use of library `chains` and `scope`. Formed are two chains: A and B. Arrows between nodes in chains are drawn by option `join=by ->` in box style. Arrows, which connect chain A with nodes "Source_1" and "Source_2" are drawn separately. Syntax `|-` is used in drawing perpendicular lines.

**Edit:** I notice a spelling error, which is now corrected. It correction I exploit also for slightly changes drawings (all nodes are now the same size).